# Error starting OneNote from command prompt

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments, microsoft-onenote-2013

When I start OneNote 2013 from a command prompt, OneNote opens, but I am getting this error:

**Microsoft Office has identified a potential security concern**

*Hyperlinks can be harmful to your computer and data. To protect your computer, click only those hyperlinks from trusted sources.*

Any way to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

#### Microsoft office has identified a potential security concern

> hyperlinks can be harmful to your computer and data. To protect your computer, click only those hyperlinks from trusted sources.

It is a "Security Alert" not an error. You can disable these security alerts.

Note:

- **Microsoft do not recommend this**.

> This article describes the risks involved when a document that you are working in contains a link to a suspicious website or when you try to open a file from a suspicious website. Microsoft Office helps protect you from these risks with settings in the Trust Center.
>
> **Enable or disable security alerts about links to suspicious websites**
>
> In Office, detection of suspicious links to websites is turned on by default. You can turn detection off so that you don't get security alerts. But we do not recommend this.
>
> 1. In an Office program, click the "File" tab.
>
>    Office 2007 doesn't have a "File" tab. Instead, click the "Office"
>      button. [image: Office button image]
> 2. Click "Options".
> 3. Click "Trust Center", and then click "Trust Center Settings".
> 4. Click "Privacy Options".
> 5. Under "Privacy Options", select or clear the "Microsoft Office documents that are from or link to suspicious Web sites" check box.
> 6. Click "OK".
>
> The following image is an example of the "Privacy Options" area of the
>   "Trust Center".
>
> [image: Privacy Options area of Trust Center]

Source [Enable or disable security alerts about links and files from suspicious websites](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Enable-or-disable-security-alerts-about-links-and-files-from-suspicious-websites-a1ac6ae9-5c4a-4eb3-b3f8-143336039bbe)